# Boundary of a countable set of real numbers

Tags: real-analysis

Let $A = \cup_{i} \{a_i\}$ where $a_i \in \mathbb{R}$. I'm trying to find the boundary of $A$.

Since there is no $\delta > 0$ s.t. $(a_i - \delta, a_i + \delta) \subset A$, I know that $\text{int}(A) = \varnothing$.

Next, I'm trying to describe the set of limit points of $A$ so to obtain $\text{cl}(A)$, from which I can identify the boundary of $A$ as $\partial(A) = \text{cl}(A) \setminus \text{int}(A)$.

Can you provide hints at how to describe the limit points of $A$?

**Edit:**

Based on the answers below, it seems that without specifying the $a_i$'s, all we can say is that $\partial A = \text{cl}(A)$.

Specifically, I have that $A = \cup_{n \in \mathbb{N}, \ k = 0, \dots, n} \Big \{ \frac{k-np}{\sqrt{np(1-p)}} \Big \}$ for fixed $p \in (0, 1)$. For increasing $n$ I can see that the singletons are getting closer, and also that $A$ "covers" more of $\mathbb{R}$ (in the sense that $a_n - |a_0|$ is increasing). Therefore I'm inclined to believe that $\text{cl}(A) = \mathbb{R}$, but I'm not sure how to arrive at this rigorously.

Comment: Take a few standard examples of countable subsets of $\mathbb{R}$. What are the limit points of those? What can you deduce?

Answer (score 1):

The closure points of $A$ are all the possible limits of sequences in $A$. Without more assumptions on $a_i$ you can't say much. The only thing you can say for sure is that the boundary of $A$ is the closure of $A$.

For instance if $A=\mathbb{Z}$ then the closure of $A$ is $A$ itself and the boundary is empty. If $A=\mathbb{Q}$ then the closure of $A$ is $\mathbb{R}$ since the rationals form a dense subset. The interior of $A$ is empty as you point out so the boundary of $A$ is $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Shouldn't the boundary be $\mathbb{R}$ in the second case?

Comment: True that, I'll correct.

Comment: Thanks for answering, see my edit!

Answer (score 1):

That will depend on $a_i$. If $a_i=i$ then $\operatorname{cl}(A)=A$ but if $a_i$ follows an enumeration of $\Bbb Q$ then $A=\Bbb Q$ and the closure is $\Bbb R$. the closure could in fact be *any* closed subset of $\Bbb R$ (all have a countable dense subset..).

All we know for sure is that if $A$ is countable, its interior is empty and its boundary equals its closure.

Comment: Thanks for answering, see my edit!